# ZIGP-Regression for count data/with AR features

Tags: time-series, generalized-linear-model, least-squares, poisson-regression

assume I have time series count data that come from a zero inflated poisson distribution (ZIGP).

My idea was to estimate a ZIGP-Regression with including AR-features (lagged values) among other features.

However, in

[https://timeseriesreasoning.com/contents/generalized-linear-regression-models/#:~:text=Therefore%20GLMs%20cannot%20be%20used,auto%2Dcorrelated%20time%20series%20data](https://timeseriesreasoning.com/contents/generalized-linear-regression-models/#:%7E:text=Therefore%20GLMs%20cannot%20be%20used,auto%2Dcorrelated%20time%20series%20data).

there was a statement that

[image]

Why is that the case ? I know that one can fit AR-models with an OLS regression, which is a special case of a GLM model, with the result of biased coefficient but consistency. Nevertheless, many textbooks use OLS as a viable way to estimate AR processes. Are there any other disadvantages of including AR-features in a ZIGP-Regression (or more general) in a GLM-regression ?